# Caching stock ticker information

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, caching

I need an advice where to cache the stock ticker info that i pull from a 3rd party service. 
The requirement is that if the ticker info is unavailable, i have to cache the last positive result set and use that as a view model to display inside the web part. Main point here is that caching has to be not just at iis process level but rather distributed across all nodes.

Using a whole list seems like an overkill while caching into the SPWeb.AllProperties is a bit awkward as pulling the latest available value is hard to do.

Any thoughts out there?

Comment: How big is the data? Is it stored in a custom in memory object?

Comment: it's only a few data points,about 8. My thought is just to serilize/deserialize using json real quick.  That's why i think building a whole list for it is way too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to use `SPWeb` property bag. This caches the data and shared across the farm and will persist through server reboots.

For adding a new property you can use following code block

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    //GET SPWEB...

    // unsafe updates are required to be able to write to the property bag
    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    // you must check to see if the collection has a value in the assigned key already
    if (!spWeb.AllProperties.ContainsKey(key))
        spWeb.Properties.Add(key, myValue);
    else
        spWeb.AllProperties[key] = myValue;

    // update the properties
    spWeb.Properties.Update();
    spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
});
```

To read a property you can use following.

```
if (currentSite.AllProperties.ContainsKey("MyItem"))
    myItem = currentSite.AllProperties["MyItem"].ToString();
```

In your specific case cache the ticker information on first load. Keep a KEY property which can be compared to take a decision whether to update the already cached data or not.

Comment: i was considering this approach as well and it should work ok as i require eventual consistency semantics.  The only thing that threw me off was that when i reviewed how the object model actually persists the data through dotPeek there is a lot of extra overhead. I think i'll go with this approach.